# Angular 2: Object passed by reference not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript

An item was previously added to the cart. Now I want to update the values of the this existing item. In the addToCart function, the findItem() function checks the cart and returns a reference to the existing item. Because the item exists, I simply assign the existing item which was returned from the findItem() function to the newItem like so: existingItem = newItem. I expect existingItem which is already in the cart to now have the values of newItem but when I print the items in the cart, existingItem still has its previous values, not the newItem values.

```
export class CartItem {
  product: Product;
  quantity: number;
  itemTotal: number;
  color: string;
  protectionPlan: string;
}

export class Cart {
  total: number = 0;
  numberOfItems: number = 0;
  items: CartItem[] = [];

  findItem(id: String) : CartItem {
    for(let i=0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      if(this.items[i].product._id == id) {
        console.log("*************** item found ********************")
        return this.items[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  addItem(newItem: CartItem) {
    let existingItem: CartItem = this.findItem(newItem.product._id);
    if(existingItem) {
      existingItem = newItem;
      //existingItem.quantity = newItem.quantity;
      console.log("update item id = " + existingItem.product._id);
      console.log("update item quantity = " + existingItem.quantity);
      console.log("update item color = " + existingItem.color);
      console.log("update item protectionPlan = " + 
existingItem.protectionPlan);            
    } else {
      this.items.push(newItem);
      this.numberOfItems++;
    }

    console.log("cart = " + JSON.stringify(this.items));
  }
}
```

Comment: The current behavior of your program is actually the expected one. Remove existingItem = newItem; and the quantity property at least should change

Comment: existingItem = newItem is how I assign the values of the new item to the item already existing in the cart. If I remove it, the item in the cart does not get the new values.

Comment: not really, check my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

This line of code:

```
let existingItem: CartItem = this.findItem(newItem.product._id);
```

Is creating an instance that is pointing to the item in the array.

This line of code:

```
existingItem = newItem;
```

Is changing that instance to point to the new item.

It is NOT replacing the item in the array with the new item.

You will either need to copy each element from the new item to the existing item OR remove the existing item from the array and add the new item.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is more a OOP related question. Ill try to explain as clear as possible:

Lets start here:

```
addItem(newItem: CartItem) {
    let existingItem: CartItem = this.findItem(newItem.product._id);
    if(existingItem) {
    ...
    }
}
```

When you enter the if block, you will have **two different pointers** referencing two, possibly different objects.

When you do the following:

```
existingItem = newItem;
```

You now have two pointers referencing **the same object.**
So basically, doing something like:

```
existingItem.quantity = newItem.quantity;
```

Has no effect, as you will overwrite a value with itself.

As you want to mutate the values of the existing object, one possiblity would be to use `Object.assign` as follows:

```
 if(existingItem) {
    Object.assign(existingItem,newItem);
 }
```

But in my opinion, mutating the internal state of the list is kind of ugly. Keeping your objects **immutable** is in most cases something good. So a different approach would be the following:

```
addItem(newItem: CartItem) {
    let index = //some function that gives you the index in the array where the existing item is, or -1 if not present
    if(index!=-1) {
      items.splice(index,1,newItem); // there is another approach with the .filter operator
      this.items = [...items];// see spread operator
    } else {
      this.items = [...items,newItem]; // see spread operator
      this.numberOfItems++; // this is kinda silly, as items.length would give you this value
    }
```

}

This way you are creating a **new list** every time that an element is updated or added.

For some more extra info about immutability and how can be used (specially in front end frameworks) take a look [here!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7IdS-PbEgI)